# Newbie - Python Django - NoReverseMatch Error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have gone through lots of related questions but I am not able to solve this issue so I though I will finally post it, I have an app 'Customers' which will hold a list of customers, currently there are two user levels
1) Customer - If I login as a Customer I would ONLY see my details and I must be able to edit and make changes to my information
2) Advisor - If I login as an Advisor I would see a list of customers and I would be able to make changes to any customer.
To achieve this I have an 'Edit' button when clicked redirects to a 'form' with the particular fields already populated, I can edit and save. Issue arises when I click on this 'Edit' I get this error "NoReverseMatch at /customer/". But when I directly navigate to the form by typing in, "localhost:8000/customer/1/edit" I could see the form.

Here's my views.py

```
 @login_required
def customer_edit(request, cust_number):
    # customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=cust_number)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        # form = CustomerForm(request.CUSTOMER, instance=customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            customer = form.save(commit=False)
            customer.cust_number = request.user
            customer.updated_date = timezone.now()
            customer.save()
            return redirect('customer', pk=cust_number)
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()
    return render(request, 'customers/customer_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Here's my appname/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^customer/$', views.customer, name='customer'),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^customer/(?P<cust_number>\d+)/edit/$', views.customer_edit, name='customer_edit'),
]
```

Here's a part of my projectname/urls.py

```
url(r'', include('customers.urls', namespace="customers"))
```

Here's my customers/forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Customer


class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('cust_number', 'name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'email', 'cell_phone',)
```

Here's my customer_edit.html

```
{% extends 'customers/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Edit Customer</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="customer-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's my customer.html

```
{% extends 'customers/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Eagle Financial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: beige;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Welcome!</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Eagle Financial Services, your Midwest Financial Services Partner.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h2 style="padding-left: 15Px">Customer Information</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr class="bg-info">
                <th>Customer ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Zip</th>
                <th>Primary Email</th>
                <th>Cell Phone</th>
                <th colspan="3">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for customer in customers %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ customer.cust_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.address }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.city }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.state }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.zipcode }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.cell_phone }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'customers:customer_edit' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </body>
    </html>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's my error,

```
NoReverseMatch at /customer/
Reverse for 'customer_edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customer/(?P<cust_number>\\d+)/edit/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/
Django Version: 1.11.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'customer_edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customer/(?P<cust_number>\\d+)/edit/$']
```

I have tried trial and errors of namespaces, but not able to solve this. Please guide me. Thanks.

I am using Python - 3.6, Django - 1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong in views

```
customer.cust_number = request.user   #Why you assign user to cust_number?
customer.updated_date = timezone.now()
customer.save()
return redirect('customer', pk=cust_number)
```

Update your view code with below:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

@login_required
def customer_edit(request, cust_number):
    # customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=cust_number)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        # form = CustomerForm(request.CUSTOMER, instance=customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            customer = form.save(commit=False)
            customer.cust_number = request.user.pk
            customer.updated_date = timezone.now()
            customer.save()
            return reverse('customers:customer_edit', request.user.pk)
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()
        return render(request, 'customers/customer_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Use this in html

```
<td><a href="{% url 'customers:customer_edit' cust_number=customer.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a></td>
```